# jQuery spiral animation

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, spiral

I recently encountered a jQuery spiral plugin. However, it doesn't seem to be working, and I'm not sure why.

I've made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thugsb/svT2Z/2/

The plugin was only made back in October (posted here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/plugin-spiral-animations), so it should be a reasonably recent version of jQuery in use. Unfortunately the maker's website is gone, so I'm unable to contact him. Any ideas how to make it work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the order your code is running in.  The spiral plugin isn't even defined when you're trying to run it.  Just put things in a different order and it works fine.  See corrected fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zNmHN/

If you look at the error console in a webkit browser (chrome, safari) you'd get a good hint.

Comment: Dumbest mistake ever! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you wanting this plugin, I've added vertical-spiralling and updated it to version 1.2. You'll find the code both on the original forum post and on github: https://github.com/thugsb/jQuery.Spiral

Let me know about any bugs, suggestions for improvement, or even just if you found it helpful. Thanks!